# Can I use Aws SQS with heroku, Nodejs Express server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I want to use heroku server with APIs and add tasks to AWS queue, and attach that queue to aws lambda. Is is possible? If yes then what are the ways?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the AWS API is publicly available on the internet, so you would be able to connect to SQS using the AWS SDK from code running inside Heroku. You would just need to configure your Heroku application with your AWS API credentials. The easiest way to do that would probably be through environment variables.

I would create an AWS IAM account with only access to push to one specific SQS queue, and use the API credentials for that account inside Heroku.

Comment: So for that I can use `sqs.sendMessage(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});` sending message. But I see people use `aws-sdk` too. what's that?

Comment: if you say AWS API Credentials what's the way to generate that? Also Can you share some refs of using SQS with nodejs express server (which hosted on heroku)  in you can find any that would be really helpful.

Comment: The `sqs` object in the code you pasted in is part of the `aws-sdk` for NodeJS. That code is using the AWS SDK. Generating and managing IAM account API keys is documented here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html